# clienttemplates.js is raising errors on Google chrome

Tags: javascript

When browsing SharePoint 2013 using google chrome I am getting following error:-

> ReferenceError: Strings is not definedReferenceError: Strings is not defined

and the Chrome Developer tools console is mentioning the following exception:-

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Strings is not defined
>   clienttemplates.js?rev=J%2BGzwlHEWSv11%2BqD9XeOaw%3D%3D:1
>   $_global_clienttemplates
>   clienttemplates.js?rev=J%2BGzwlHEWSv11%2BqD9XeOaw%3D%3D:1 (anonymous
>   function) clienttemplates.js?rev=J%2BGzwlHEWSv11%2BqD9XeOaw%3D%3D:

so how I can solve this exception? and could this problem be related to the fact that I have reorder, some of the master page components. for example I move the search button to be on the left upper corner, and I move the site title to be at the top of the page beside the company logo.

Answer (score 2):

Load the SP scripts first using SP.SOD.LoadMultiple as shown below

```
SP.SOD.loadMultiple(['sp.js', 'clienttemplates.js','clientforms.js','clientpeoplepicker.js','autofill.js'], function(){
//your func here

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The object `Strings` is defined in `sts_strings.js`, located in a language-specific subfolder of the `layouts` folder. For example, assuming you have an English version: `/_layouts/15/1033/sts_strings.js`. You should include this `JavaScript` reference before the reference for `clienttemplates.js`.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is either one of the following:

- Custom JavaScript code which isn't downloading
- Custom Master page with broken link to strings JS
- A plugin in Chrome which is preventing the page from loading correctly (popup blocker etc)